# PHP convert String number with whitespace to Float

Tags: php, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a class with field `price`. It's stored in database as `varchar(100)` (don't ask me why, not my idea) and I have to retrieve it and divide it by the other price, which is also retrieved from database.

In database number looks like: `1 000.00` - thousands' parts are separated with whitespace (one million looks like ->`1 000 000.00`).

I try it on website: w3resource.com/php with an online interpreter.

What I do is...

```
$a = "3 999.99";
$b = "1 500.11";

$aa = floatval(str_replace(' ', '', $a));
$bb = floatval(str_replace(' ', '', $b));

$c = $aa - $bb;
echo $aa . ' - ' . $bb . ' = ' . $c;
```

and it displays correct output:

`3999.99 - 1500.11 = 2499.88`

But when I do it in my project, it's like:

```
$a = "3 999.99";
$b = "1 500.11";

$aa = floatval(str_replace(' ', '', $a));
$bb = floatval(str_replace(' ', '', $b));

$c = $aa - $bb;
echo $aa . ' - ' . $bb . ' = ' . $c;
```

```
3999.99 - 1500.11 = 2.00
```

In my project, price is truncated - everything that is after the whitespace is truncated and the calculations are performed only on the first digits, in my case it's: `3 - 1`

Could anybody tell me where to look for a bug?

Comment: Just add `var_dump($aa, $bb);` and look output

Comment: I would recommend that you change the database table to int and then store all values as ints instead of floats (or strings of floats) because of the [float precision problem](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). So instead of saving `3 999.99`, you multiply it by 100, saving `399999`. This will help you going forward and will prevent possible float issues and will be easier to work with. Having the price as formatted string in the db is just wrong and only adds unnecessary complexity for no gain at all.

Comment: I know that it's not a good, rather strange idea to store that kind of values as strings, but let's assume that I cannot change that - is there anything else that I can do?

@Slava Rozhnew ~ I dumped it and it shows me that I subtract ```3 - 1``` not what I wanted - ```3999.99 - 1500.11```

Comment: To be honest, you should do everything you can to make that change as soon as possible. This question is already proof of it causing issues. Specially when we're talking prices. What you're doing now is similar to fixing cracks in the foundation of a house using duct tape. It's a quick fix, but I wouldn't want to live there, or even visit.

Comment: If you don't want to multiply values by 100, you could use [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). So instead of ```$c = $aa - $bb;``` you could use ```$c = bcsub($aa, $bb);```

Comment: I am aware of what you say - and think exactly the same (this kind of fix should be only temporary) - but I'm not entitled to make such decision, but I will put that idea forward.
I don't really know what someone's wanted to achieve with that type of data being stored in databse. 
But thank You for explanation.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question... in that database prices that are stored are kind of millions or even tens of millions i.e.```10 000 000.00``` or ```100 000 000.00``` - will it be okay to multiply it by 100 as you said and store it as an ```int```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a non visible character as the thousand separator character. It's more safe to filter all characters except digits and `.` when sanitizing the input string. This can be achieved with the `preg_replace` function.

Your script can be modified to something like this:

```
$a = "3 999.99";
$b = "1 500.11";

$aa = floatval(preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $a));
$bb = floatval(preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $b));

$c = $aa - $bb;
echo $aa . ' - ' . $bb . ' = ' . $c;
```

Additionally, it's a bit dangerous and non exact to use floats when handling money in particular. Please have a look at this repository which helps a lot with this problem: https://github.com/moneyphp/money

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake is `price` as `varchar(100)` - it's a `string`, it can be displayed in a million ways, but it cannot be recalculated. There are no excuses. It should be an `integer` or `decimal` and any subtraction should be done using SQL.

The second error is when you use a `float` as the value for `price`. Leave php `float` for astrophysicists, use `int`.

```
$a = "3 999.99";
$b = "1 500.11";

$a1 = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $a);
$b1 = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $b);

var_dump($a1, $b1);                         // test
echo'<hr>';

$c1 = $a1 - $b1;

var_dump($a1, $b1, $c1);                    // test
```

formatting to display:

```
echo substr_replace(substr_replace($c1,' ',-5,0), '.',-2,0);
```